# How to list the machine types within a specific zone using gcp cli?

Tags: command-line-interface, gcloud, google-cloud-platform

I list the set of machine types in GCP using:

```
gcloud compute machine-types list
```

Also I list the machine types and its zone using:

```
gcloud compute machine-types list --format=value"(NAME,ZONE)"
```

Both commands give the right output with no errors.

But I want to list the set of machine types in a specific zone.
I tried the following:

```
gcloud compute machine-types list --format="value(NAME,ZONE=asia-southeast1-a)"
```

which outputs this error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.compute.machine-types.list) Expected ) in projection
>   expression [    table(
>         name,
>         zone.basename(),
>         guestCpus:label=CPUS,
>         memoryMb.size(units_in=MiB, units_out=GiB, precision=2):label=MEMORY_GB,
>         deprecated.state:label=DEPRECATED
>       )  value(NAME,ZONE *HERE* =asia-southeast1-a)].

I want to list the machine types only in asia-southeast1-a using a gcloud command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [topic filter](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters) with the `--filter` option:

```
gcloud compute machine-types list --filter="zone: asia-southeast1-a" --format=value"(NAME,ZONE)"
```